# Output data using PHP organised by levels

Tags: php

I have data in a table that's stored this way:

```
level | name
    1 | Name 1
    1 | Name 2
    1 | Name 3
    2 | Name 4
    2 | Name 5
    5 | Name 6
    5 | Name 7
   10 | Name 8
```

I select data using php with a simple select that select's all data.

From the data I select, how can I, using PHP, organize and output the data like below?

I trying to display it grouped by levels.

So here `level 1` and `level 2` are `premium` levels, `level 5` are `midlevel` and `level 10` are `budget`. How can I do this using php?

Getting it grouped by levels and giving it headings is where I'm stuck. Can you please help me with this?

**Desired results:**

```
Premium //All level 1,2
-------
Name 1
Name 2
Name 3
Name 4
Name 5

Mid //All level 5
-------
Name 6
Name 7

Budget //All level 10s
--------
Name 8
```

Comment: Are you using mysql for the table?

Comment: And the desired result is stored in table?

Comment: @david No, the desired result is output to the web page. What's stored in the table is up there.

Comment: Why not use an `if` or `switch` statement?

Comment: Please show us what you've got so far.

Comment: @jcsanyi I already have. I use a single select that selects all data and outputs it. I'm stuck with grouping it like in the desired results.

Comment: Please **show** us. I don't see a select anywhere in your question - or anything that outputs it.

Comment: @Norman No PHP code that you tried sort it by your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$premium = array();
$mid = array();
$budget = array();
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY level")
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    if ($row['level'] == 1 || $row['level'] == 2){
        $premium[] = $row['name'];
    }
    else if ($row['level'] == 5){
        $mid[] = $row['name'];
    }
    else if ($row['level'] == 10){
        $budget[] = $row['name'];
    }
}
echo 'Premium<br/>';
foreach ($premium as $val)
    echo $val.'<br/>';
echo 'Mid<br/>';
foreach ($mid as $val)
    echo $val.'<br/>';
echo 'Budget<br/>';
foreach ($budget as $val)
    echo $val.'<br/>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code to group into three parts assuming that you are able to connect 
   with myqsli database and php

```
  <?php
    $mid=0;
    $premium=0;
    $budjet=0;
    $sql=  "select * from table order by level";
    if ($result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            if (($row['level']==1)&&($row['level']==2))
            {
                if($premium==0){
                    echo "Premium";
                    $premium=1;
                }
            }
            if (($row['level']==5)
            {
                if($mid==0){
                    echo "MID";
                    $mid=1;
                }
            }
            if (($row['level']==10)
            {
                if($budjet==0){
                    echo "Budjet";
                    $budjet=1;
                }
            }
            echo $row['name']."<br>";
        }
    }
```

Comment: +1 just for somebody **finally** providing an answer that uses a supported mysql library.

Comment: You just connect with mysql and use it .if u need connection string tell me

Answer (score 0):

**Use Array.
Try this:**

```
$premium = "";
    $midlevel = "";
    $budget = "";
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table_name";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        if($row['level'] == 1 || $row['level'] == 2)
            $premium .= $row['name'];
        else if($row['level'] == 5)
            $midlevel .= $row['name'];
        else if($row['level'] == 10)
            $budget .= $row['name'];
    }

    echo "Premium : <br />".$premium;
```

Print variables as you Required.

Comment: You only print as a string, not array

Comment: @david im suggest use array if string is not work as you required

Comment: You said you use array for this code. But I only see the string

Answer (score -1):

**PHP 5.4+ REQUIRED**
If you are not using PHP 5.4+, you will need to change the `[]` to proper `array()`.

Assuming you use a `$rows` variable which holds an array of all your rows, you can do something like this.

```
<?php

foreach ($rows as $row)
{
    switch ($row['level']) {
        case 1:
            $premium[] = $row['name'];
            break;
        case 2:
            $premium[] = $row['name'];
            break;
        case 5:
            $midlevel[] = $row['name'];
            break;
        case 10:
            $budget[] = $row['name'];
            break;
    }
}
```

Once this `foreach` runs, you will end up with three arrays with the names like you want. `$premium`, `$midlevel`, and `$budget`.

**EDIT**

Using your while loop, you'd do it like this.  Although, I prefer the switch/case above.

```
<?php

$query = "SELECT * FROM table_name";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    switch ($row['level']) {
        case 1:
            $premium[] = $row['name'];
            break;
        case 2:
            $premium[] = $row['name'];
            break;
        case 5:
            $midlevel[] = $row['name'];
            break;
        case 10:
            $budget[] = $row['name'];
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: ?? Why does this require PHP 5.4. This should work with any version of PHP, including PHP 4.

Comment: I'm lost. Where you used something that require PHP 5.4? Only thing I see is that you're still suggesting to use `mysql_*` instead of `mysqli_*`

Comment: The new array syntax in PHP 5.4 allows me to create and add to the arrays using just `[]` instead of having to do `array()`.  This was introduced in PHP 5.4

Comment: @SajanParikh that's incorrect. That has always been possible in PHP.

Comment: @speccode that code was copied from another reply here, I simply inserted my switch into that.

Comment: @speccode I'm not sure what planet you're on, but here it is...the second bullet point. http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

Comment: @SajanParikh That is not what you're using. The syntax you're using has always been supported.

Comment: @SajanParikh funny. On 5.4 you can do this `$arr = []`. `$arr[]` was from always.

Comment: @speccode Yes, but prior to PHP 5.4, before doing `$arr[]`, the array had to already exist.

Comment: @SajanParikh And even in 5.4, it should exist. Your code will produce a PHP warning or notice.